# "Users & Groups" does not display groups on Ventura 13.2

Tags: permission, user-account, settings

On Ventura 13.2, when I go to the "Users & Groups" settings page, no groups are displayed and there does not seem to be any way to make them appear.

The "macOS User Guide" indicates that there should be a section called "Groups" where I can "View the list of groups. Click the Info button  next to a group name to view details and make changes. See Change Group settings.", but there is no such section.

I am an admin account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default groups like `admin` or `staff` don't show up in Users & Groups. You can add your own groups by clicking **Add Account...** and selecting "Group" from the "New Account" dropdown. Groups created this way can afterwards be managed in Settings.